# Surjectivity of an operator which satisfies an inf-sup condition.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be Banach spaces and let $A\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y')$ be the operator defined by $$A(u)(v)=a(u,v),\quad\forall u\in X, \forall v\in Y,$$ where $a:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded bilinear form. Then, $A$ is surjective if and only if, the following inf-sup condition is satisfied, $$\sup_{x\in X\backslash\{0\}}\dfrac{|a(x,v)|}{\|x\|_X}\geq \alpha \|v\|_{Y},\quad \forall v\in Y.$$

My attempt:

So far I have proved that if $A$ is surjective, then the inf-sup condition is satisfied. On the other hand, let $\varphi\in Y'$. My goal is to find $x\in X$ such that $A(x)=\varphi$. How can I define this element $x\in X$?